# How to use nested marshmallow schemas with Mongoengines lazyReferenceFields?

Tags: flask, serialization, mongoengine, marshmallow

I have the following marshmallow schemas and mongoengine classes defined:

```
class DataReport(Document):
    id = ObjectIdField(required=True)
    firmware_statistics_report_reference_id = LazyReferenceField(FirmwareReport, required=True)
    ...

class DataReportSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Str()
    firmware_statistics_report_reference_id = fields.Nested(FirmwareReportSchema)
    ...

class FirmwareReport(Document):
    id = ObjectIdField(required=True)
    firmware_id_list = ListField(required=True))
    ...

class FirmwareReportSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Str()
    firmware_id_list = fields.List(fields.Str())
    ...

report = DataReport().objects.get(pk=...)
DataReportSchema().dump(report)
```

Is it possible to dump the nested schema with the LazyReferenceField from mongoengine? What I want is to get the all fields defined in the child schema, but I did not find a way to get the full schema data when it is referenced with the LazyReferenceField.

If I dump the DataReportSchema I will only get the referenced Object-ID and not the fields from the FirmwareReportSchema, which makes sense since it is a LazyReference until I call mongoengines fetch() function. I assume there must be a way to fetch the LazyReference before it is dumped, but I do not understand how.

Is it possible to fetch() the LazyReference before the marshmallow dump() in order to get the full dump from the child schema and not only an Object-ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I found the solution myself. Instead of using the fields.Nested method it is possible to use the fields.Method method. Then it is possible to fetch() the id within a custom method:

```
class DataReportSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Str()
    report_date = fields.DateTime()
    firmware_statistics_report_reference_id = fields.Method("get_firmware_schema")

    def get_firmware_schema(self, data_statistics_report):
      firmware_report = data_statistics_report.firmware_statistics_report_reference_id.fetch()
      return FirmwareStatisticsReportSchema().dump(firmware_report)
```